# How to disable @Configuration initialization in WebFluxTest?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-webflux

I would like to write tests for reactive controller using `@WebFluxTest` annotation, mocking all dependencies.

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest { 
    
    @MockBean
    SomeService service;

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webClient;

    //some tests
}
```

From what I understand, the `WebFluxTest` annotation shall apply only configuration relevant to WebFlux tests (i.e. `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, etc.), but not another beans.

My spring boot app contains a number of `@Configuration` classes that configure a number of beans (annotated as `@Bean`). Some of those configurations have also dependencies (autowired by constructor).

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyConfig {

    private final AnotherConfig anotherConfig;

    @Bean
    //...
}
```

When I run my web flux tests, I can see the context initialization contains an attempt to initialize the `MyConfig` (and it fails because of the missing dependency which comes from 3rd party auto-configured lib). How can I configure the test to skip initialization of all of these?

I am able to exclude the problematic configuration class only by excluding auto configuration of the whole app.

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = {MyApplication.class})
public class MyControllerTest { ... }
```

where `MyApplication` is the spring boot app autoscanning those configuration classes.

But how can I achieve to skip initialization of `MyConfig` only? Or even better, how can I achieve to only include a list of configurations to be initialized?

Comment: It shouldn't, and when it does this generally is due to those being either imported or there is additional config on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. In either case testing has no way of excluding those classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
@ActiveProfiles("YOUR_ENV_OTHER_THAN_TEST")
```

below or above @Configuration

For multiple environments..

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles ={env1, env2,env3})
```